# how to add a sum field in a view?

Tags: drupal-6, view, drupal-views

I use Drupal 6.26.
I have created a view for a custom content type that has a price field. I want to add a sum row at the end of of view (which is in table style) to show the total price. How can I do it?
Would you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Views Calc](http://drupal.org/project/views_calc/) module. It does exactly what you're asking.

You need to install it, and change your view's "Style" setting to "Views Calc Table". Then in the Style's options you'll see "Column calculations", where you can select "Display calculations" and "SUM" for the appropriate fields.

Make sure your field settings for the price fields are outputting normal plain text/number string (as opposed to some kind of link or something), so that Views Calc will have no problem using the data for its calculations.